# How do I perform a setValue on a formControl in a formArray?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How do I perform a setValue on a formControl that is in a formArray? I have an input box that gets the value of a field. Upon the `(blur)` function, the field will add the value in the input box and add it with the value of the other field. I can get the value of it, but whenever I add a row, that value will still show in the next row.

in my html:

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container formArrayName="cap_values">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Investor</th>
                    <th scope="col">Class</th>
                    <th scope="col">New shares</th>
                    <th scope="col">New options allocated</th>
                    <th scope="col">Investment (S$)</th>
                    <th scope="col">Total shares</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngFor="let item of capValues.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" formControlName="name"></td>
                    <td>Ord</td>
                    <td><input type="number" #newShares value="{{ Math.round(item.value.investment / unitPrice) || 0}}"
                            disabled></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="number" formControlName="investment"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" formControlName="totalShares" value="{{this.total}}" (blur)="newTotal(newShares.value -- item.value.totalShares)"></td>
                </tr>
                {{this.capValues.value[i].totalShares | json}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </ng-container>
    <div>Unit Price: <input type="number" formControlName="unitPrice"></div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addRow()">Add</button>
</form>
```

my .ts:

```
export class CapTableComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  Math = Math;
  total: any;

  newTotal(value: number) {
    this.total = value;
  }
}
```

This was what I was trying to talk about. the value in the first row is still showing in the second and so on. 
[image]

One way would be get the index at that row and set the value there. Another way that I think can be done is by making `this.total` be dynamic in each row. I am uncertain of doing either of these. If there is anything more that I need to provide, do let me know. Thanks alot.

Comment: you can use `patchValue()`. Please find in Angular docs  https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value

Comment: @Chaitanya i got a `TypeError: value.forEach is not a function` when I tried this out.

Comment: That is because your value variable is not an array

Comment: @TonyNgo i can iterate through each index in the row. how do i set the value accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily set the value using an index.

```
**newTotal(index) {
 const capValueForm = form.controls['cap_values] as FormArray;
 capValueForm.controls.forEach((data, index) => {
  /* your operations and setValue*/
  data.controls[index].get('newShares').setValue(/* your value */)
```

})
}**